# Как задать таймаут выполнения процесса?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, timeout

Есть задача:

```bash
run script.sh >> log.file &
```

Как задать таймаут? Допустим, если задача выполняется более 60 секунд, то кикаем ее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого есть команда [`timeout`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/coreutils/timeout.1.en.html) из пакета coreutils.

Например, чтобы для вашей команды задать таймаут равный 60 секундам, выполните следующую команду:

```bash
timeout 60 ВАША_КОМАНДА
```

Answer (score 0):

Но допустим у вас нет `timeout` или есть жгучее желание собрать свой велосипед(как у меня)) Тогда можно попробовать что-нибудь такое:

```
# зададим время ожидания - 3(сек.)
runtime=3

# Запускаем искомую команду в фоне и записываем её pid в переменную $pid
some_command & pid=$!

# Запускаем в фоне подпрограмму которая будеть ждать $runtime секунд
# затем выполнит kill $pid
(sleep $runtime; kill $pid) &


# Тест
 sleep 20   &   pid=$!
(sleep 3; kill $pid) &
```

Comment: "нет timeout" — это очень вряд ли, потому что coreutils.

Comment: waitpid не хватает